# What is the firebase rule to validate if a field is decimal number?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a class where one of the field is "weight". I need to validate if weight lies in a certain value range. This is the rule I have defined:

```
"User":{".validate":
        "newData.child('weight').val()>=1 &&
         newData.child('weight').val()<=300"
           }
```

However, when I use the simulator and test with decimal values,write is denied.
How to validate these decimal values?

Comment: Look at this https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#isnumber

Comment: This works fine for me. Are you sure you also have a `.write` rules that evaluates to `true`? Without that, even valid data won't be writable.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes I do have a write rule that evaluates to true

Comment: Thanks. isNumber() worked fine. I just happened to enclose the number in Strings which was giving error.